# Enabling fail2ban 0.10 on ipv6

Tags: ipv6, fail2ban

I just upgraded to fail2ban version 0.10 on debian via apt-get.

I see things like this in 'iptables -n -L':

```
Chain f2b-apache-auth (1 references)
...
Chain f2b-pam-generic (1 references)
...
```

but I don't see anything similar in the output of 'ip6tables -n -L'.
Is there something specific I need to do to enable fail2ban 0.10 for
iptables/ip6tables?

Comment: Interesting. I just spot checked a couple of fail2ban 0.10 installs and found they were not doing anything with IPv6.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that fail2ban doesn't create these chains until it has an entry to put in a chain.  Hence why the chains don't exist.

After installing fail2ban 0.10, about a day later, I saw my first ban on ipv6 and it indeed created the chain at that point.

Good to know, just have to be a little patient!